# Why is it possible to assign a variable of type any to a void type in typescript

Tags: typescript

In typescript this code is valid and compiles, but I don't get why:

```
const a: any = "Not void";

const x: void = a;
```

Why is this allowed? The documentation says that void is the opposite of any, so assign any to void looks like an error to me (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says that:

> void is **a little like** the opposite of any

So it's not **exactly** the opposite of `any`.
It also says that:

> Declaring variables of type void is not useful because you can only
>   assign undefined or null to them

But you can also do this:

```
const x: void = "" as null;
```

And the same will work with `any`:

```
const x: void = "" as any;
```

The reason is that when you use `any` you basically tell the compiler that the value can be of any type and that it shouldn't type check it.
`any` contains all possible types, including `null`, `undeinfed` and `void`.

You can always bypass the compiler type checks with `any`, more examples:

```
const y: number = "" as any;
const a: string = 0 as any;
```